# How to calculate throughput if there is network traffic

Tags: networking

I came across this question in a textbook, but there are no solutions and I'm not sure how to solve this.

The question is: Suppose Host A wants to send a large file to Host B. The path from Host A to Host B has three links of rates R1=500Kb/s, R2=2Mb/s and R3=1Mb/s. Assuming that there is another busy flow that travels through the same set of links (say from Host C to Host D), what will be the throughput for this file transfer?

I know that the throughput for no traffic would be the min(R1, R2, R3), so would the throughput with traffic be the max(R1, R2, R3)?

Comment: Throughput can never be max(R1, R2, R3).  The connection is only as fast as its slowest link.  There's also a lot of variables involved, such as how the connections handle multiple requests.  Is it on a first-come, first server?  Round-Robbin?

Comment: Question wasn't very specific, so I was assuming that hosts A and C were sending at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Speed = min(R1,R2,R3) / number_of_connections
```